# How to make lftp auto completion case insensitive?

Tags: lftp

lftp seems case sensitive by default. How can I make it insensitive, for commands such as `cd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting will do the trick:

```
set cmd:cls-completion-default -FBai
```

The option `-i` makes completion case insensitive.